# INSERT VALUES TO A COLUMN WITH 2 FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, insert

I have tables "course" and "student" with n-n relationship,so I create another table name "course_student" to handle that.

````
--Table course--
    .id            //primary key 
    .name  ```
--Table student--
    .id.          //primary key
    .name
--Table course_student
    .course_id   //primary key + foreign key course(id)
    .student_id  //primary key + foreign key student(id)
````

I try to insert values into "course_student" but it replies with wrong syntax

```
INSERT INTO course_student(course_id , student_id ) 
VALUES (
SELECT id FROM course WHERE name = "K01", 
SELECT id FROM student WHERE name = "Duy"   
);
```

Can you help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You must use `INSERT .. SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO course_student ( course_id , student_id ) 
SELECT course.id, student.id
FROM course 
CROSS JOIN student 
WHERE course.name = 'K01'
  AND student.name = 'Duy';
```

Comment: As a note to the OP, add a unique constraint for name in course and student.

Comment: Oh  I understand now. Thank you so much

Comment: @Lennart according to the question (or what I understand), the PK is `(course_id, student_id)`

Comment: Yes, but I mean in the course table and in the student table. If several courses are named the same, the insert is likely to result in something unwanted

Comment: The question assumes that each course/student can be identified by its `name` value. If not then the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Each sub-SELECT needs its own parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO course_student(course_id , student_id ) 
VALUES (
    ( SELECT id FROM course WHERE name = "K01" ), 
    ( SELECT id FROM student WHERE name = "Duy" )  
);
```